# Dbus Signals and Slots in Qt

Tags: qt, signals, qdbus

I need to catch the signal from QDBus and I am new for this and don't know how to catch the signal from QDbus. Please explain with examples so i can understand.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options:

1. Use `QDBusConnection::connect()`
2. Create a generic `QDBusInterface` object for the remote interface and use it as the sender in a normale `QObject::connect()` withn `SIGNAL/SLOT` macros
3. Generate a specific interface object from the service's XML introspection data using the `qdbusxml2cpp` code generator

The [D-Bus Chat example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-chat-example.html) uses both (1) and (3) and has (2) in a commented line for reference.

Comment: Yes but i have a signal with arguments like  newSignal(object path, Dict of{String, Dict of {String, Variant }} ) .  Here I don't know how to declare this signal with these arguments, Can you guide me about this

Comment: You could try a `QVariantMap` as the second argument or a `QMap<QString, QVariantMap>`.

Comment: I have declared slot in a class as below                                                             public slots:                                                                  
   int Devicefound(QDBusObjectPath path, QMap<QString, QVariantMap> map){                              
       qDebug() << "DEVICE FOUND >>>>>>> ", path;                               
    }

Comment: I have declared slot in a class as below 
slots: 
   int Devicefound(QDBusObjectPath path, QMap<QString, QVariantMap> map){
qDebug() << "DEVICE FOUND",;
}
and calling a function as below but also unable to catch the signal
void BlueTooth::startDiscovery(bool state) {
QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect("org.bluez","/","org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager","InterfacesAdded",this,"Devicefound");
}

Comment: The slot argument should be `SLOT(Devicefound(...))`, like in a `QObject::connect()`